# How to use CardLayout with Multiple JPanels?

Tags: java, user-interface, cardlayout

The first screen is 2 JPanels split using JSplitPane. How do I switch to another screen that is set up the same. I tried putting the first 2 JPanels into a panel container but that doesn't work. Then I tried to just leave them seperate without a container but then only the second bottom panel showed up. How to use cardLayout to switch between two formatted Panels. If three is another way to do this then please tell because CardLayout is a little too difficult to use when all the panels have to be formatted a certain way.

```
public class Quizlet extends JFrame implements ActionListener  {

public JPanel Container, FTop, FBottom,QTop,QBottom;
public JScrollPane Scroll;
public JSplitPane FirstSplit,QuesSplit,FinalSplit;
public JTextArea Text;
public JButton Start, Next, Finish;
public JTextField Answer;
public JLabel Hello,Ans;
CardLayout Switch = new CardLayout();


public Quizlet () {

    Container = new JPanel();   
    Container.setLayout(Switch);
    Container.add(FTop, null);
    Container.add(FBottom,null);
    Switch.show(FTop,null);
    Switch.show(QBottom, null);


    FTop = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());


    Hello = new JLabel("Please Click start to begin");
    FTop.add(Hello, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    FBottom = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());


    Start = new JButton("Start Session");
    Start.addActionListener(this);

    FBottom.add(Start,BorderLayout.CENTER);

    FirstSplit = new JSplitPane();
    FirstSplit.setTopComponent(FTop);                  // at the top we want our "topPanel"
    FirstSplit.setBottomComponent(FBottom); 

    add(FirstSplit);
    FirstSplit.setOrientation(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);  
    FirstSplit.setDividerLocation(200);                    
    FirstSplit.setTopComponent(FTop);                  
    FirstSplit.setBottomComponent(FBottom); 

    //Second Screen top component

    QTop = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    Ans = new JLabel("Answer");
    c.gridx=0;
    c.gridy=0;
    QTop.add(Ans, c);


    Answer = new JTextField(12);
    c.gridx=0;
    c.gridy=1;
    QTop.add(Answer, c);
    //Second Screen Bottom Component
    QBottom = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    Next = new JButton("Next Question");
    QBottom.add(Next,BorderLayout.CENTER);

    //Second screen Split
    QuesSplit = new JSplitPane();
    QuesSplit.setTopComponent(QTop);                  
    QuesSplit.setBottomComponent(QBottom); 

    add(QuesSplit);
    QuesSplit.setOrientation(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);  
    QuesSplit.setDividerLocation(200);                    
    QuesSplit.setTopComponent(QTop);                  
    QuesSplit.setBottomComponent(QBottom); 



    setSize(500,500);
    setVisible(true);
    setTitle("The Quiz");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    pack();


}
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource()==Start) {
        Switch.show(QTop, null);
        Switch.show(QBottom, null);
    }
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Quizlet show = new Quizlet();
            }
        });
    }
}
```